# Excel function to choose a value greater than or less that a particular value in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a data set something like this

```
Units   Price
   1    15
 100    10
 150    9
 200    8
50000   7
```

I need the output as Price with respect to quantity.

Example- If Input value is 90 it should give price as 15
If input is 210 it should give value as 8.

However,sadly I cannot use IF statement.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`

```
=INDEX(B1:B5,MATCH(lookup_value,A1:A5,1))
```

This assumes `Units` are in column **A** and `Price` is in column **B**

---

Make sure you understand both functions:

- [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
- [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) - particularly the reason for the `,1)` at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1). This is probably a bit easier although INDEX/MATCH is more versatile:-

```
=VLOOKUP(Lookup_value,$A$2:$B$6,2,TRUE)
```